# How can I add a prefix to the path from which Vue imports it's component chunks?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, import, vue-router

I just added VueRouter to my project and I have an issue where it's not getting the correct asset url.
Instead of it being

```
www.example.com/js/0.main.js
```

The url it creates is

```
www.example.com/0.main.js
```

How can I add the `/js/` prefix

Answer (score 1):

Got it just had to add

```
publicPath
```

to the output field in webpack